# multiple access to the debug.log file creating unordered files

Tags: log4j2, rollingfileappender, crontrigger

I am using log4j2.xml for logging. 3 instances of my application are simultaneously writing to the debug.log file (with Rollingfile appender and CronTriggeringPolicy). But debug.log files are not getting generated sequentially and some sequences and logs are missing during multiple access. If I test with single access, it is working as expected.

```
<Appenders>
        <RollingFile name="application" fileName="${log-path}/debug.log"
            filePattern="${log-path}/debug.log.%i">
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>[%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS}]%5p [%t] (%F:%M:%L) - %m%n</pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <CronTriggeringPolicy schedule="0 0/2 * 1/1 * ? *" />               
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy fileindex="min" min="1" max="5" />
        </RollingFile>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's expected behavior. You could (artificially) get serialized lines, if you separate your log file by `thread` (the `%t` you are printing in your pattern).

The lines written with the same `%t` value, will be in the **correct order**.

On the other hand, if you are serious about logging properly, you might want to consider using [LOG4J's MDC](https://veerasundar.com/blog/2009/10/log4j-mdc-mapped-diagnostic-context-what-and-why/).

Answer (score 0):

When 3 instances of your application are running simultaneously and logging in the same file, you can not expect sequential logs.

Reason is when 3 instances are running, it means 3 separate `processes` are running and these 3 separate `processes` are trying to write to a single file.

Writing to a file involves `locking` the file resource, write and then release the lock. So, sometimes, 1 process will get the lock and write it. Meanwhile, other 2 process will keep waiting and if there `buffer` will get filled, some logs will get missed and this cycle will keep on going for other processes of the application.

For such situations, you should use some log daemon like [rsyslog](http://www.rsyslog.com/) using [log4j2 SyslogAppender](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#SyslogAppender) or easy solution is to log in separate files by each parallel instance of the application.